# Open a standard record page in edit mode Using URL

Tags: custom-button, button

I have to open an order object which is linked to a case and the case is further linked to contact.

I have to get an Edit contact button on Order to edit the order information.

I have created a button with

Content Source As : URL

In the body of the code : `/apex/{!Order__c.Case__c}/e?&retURL=/{!Case.Id}&saveURL=/{!Case.Id}`

but I am not able to get the Contact object using this since

```
/apex/{!Order__c.Case__r.ContactId}/e?&retURL=/{!Case.Id}&saveURL=/{!Case.Id}
```

thows message of Invalid URl . Please suggest

Comment: Remove the `/apex` i.e. use `/{!Order__c.Case__r.ContactId}/e?&retURL=/{!Case.Id}&saveURL=/{!Case.Id}` as you appear to be using the default URL pattern rather than a Visualforce page.

Comment: Even after using this I am getting the error that {!Order__c.Case__r.ContactId} does not exist

Comment: Can't we use the look up fields of the case to populate contact

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this button again?  You say you are trying to edit the Order, but it seems like you are trying to get to the edit screen for the contact from the order page.  Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The edited contact details are required to flow from Contact to order. But my button which on Order is not able to work with the merge field of {!Order__c.Case__r.ContactId}

Comment: Well based on the URLyou are trying to open the edit page of the contact, not have the contact info flow through.  Are you trying to edit or create a new record.  By the sounds of it, you are trying to create a new record with Contact data prefilled.  Is this correct?

Comment: no i am trying to edit the existing contact

Comment: HI, Please make sure that you have profile permission to all objects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

`{!Order__c.Case__r.ContactId}` is a typo?

If you have a custom object called Order__c, the relationship is Order__r

```
{!Order__r.Case__r.ContactId}
```

If you're using standard Order Object, is it

```
{!Order.Case__r.ContactId}
```

And then the Case Id reference is `{!Order.Case__c}`?

Comment: Order is a custom object for me and case object is standard.I have tried this but this is not working {!Order__r.Case__r.ContactId}

Comment: You were right the first time, with 
`{!Order__c.Case__r.ContactId}`. Your URL is invalid because it has `?&` next to each other. Try taking the first `&` out

Comment: I am getting the error "Error: Field Order__c.Case__r.ContactId does not exist. Check spelling." for  {!Order__c.Case__r.ContactId}

Comment: Does your Order__c object have a field called Case__c that is a link to the standard Case object?

Comment: yes, Order__c is having a look up for case

Comment: Is is a like that the formula fields do not understand third level links.

Comment: @user2703132 If you are having trouble getting the relationships, try using the Schema browser on Force.com IDE or Force.com Explorer. Sometimes it could be just something as simple as getting the wrong relationship name. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Tools

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be:

```
/{!Order__r.Case.ContactId}/e?retURL=%2F{!Order__r.Case__c}&saveURL=%2F{!Order__r.Case__c}
```

ContactId is a standard field on Case, so doesn't require the custom __r relationship syntax.